# Double Integration for Ellipse $\frac {x^2}{4} + \frac {y^2}{36} =1 $

Tags: multiple-integral

I have to evaluate the integral for the region covered by $$\frac {x^2}{4} + \frac {y^2}{36} =1 $$ for which I use the change of variables $$x=2u$$ $$y=6v$$ and I get the answer as $$6\pi$$ but isn't the area of ellipse $$\pi ab$$ by which I should get $12\pi$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you show how you get the $6\pi$? The change of variable is correct, so you would need to integrate over $$u^2+v^2=1$$This last integral should be $\pi$, and you have $2\cdot6$ from the change of variable.

Comment: You should have a double integral. If $u$ is between $-1$ and $1$, then $v$ is between $\pm\sqrt{1-u^2}$

Comment: Now it gets confusing: where is $u^2-v^2$ coming from?

Comment: I get Jacobian = 12 i.e $$dudv=\frac {1}{12}dxdy$$ so the integration is $$12 \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-u^2}}^{\sqrt{1-u^2}} u^2+v^2 dudv$$ which with polar co-ordinates comes down to  $$12 \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} r^2 rdrd\theta$$ which evaluates to $6\pi$

Comment: $$\frac {x^2}{4} + \frac {y^2}{36} =1 $$ with the substitution of x=2u and y=6v results in $$u^2+v^2$$

Comment: See my comment above. To find the area, you integrate $$\iint_D dx dy$$ So after change of variables, you have an integral over a disk of radius $1$ of $du dv$

Comment: $u^2-v^2$ was a mistake...m sorry

Comment: Then $du dv$ becomes $r dr d\theta$, no $r^2$

Comment: are you telling me that the above integral does not result in the area but evaluating $$\int \int dxdy$$ gives me the area of the region because in that case, in my polar co-ordinates my integral would $$12 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 r drd\theta$$ which does evaluate to $12\pi$

Comment: thanks a lot....but then what region was I evaluating over then...if it wasn't the area of the ellipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Area of ellipse $= \displaystyle \int_{-2}^{2} \displaystyle \int_{- \sqrt {36-9x^2}}^{\sqrt {36-9x^2}} dxdy$

Using replacement $2u = x, 6v = y$,

$= 12 \displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1} \displaystyle \int_{- \sqrt {1-u^2}}^{\sqrt {1-u^2}} dudv = 24 \displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt {1-u^2} \, du = 24 \displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sqrt {1-\sin^2 \theta} \, \cos\theta d\theta$

$= 24 \displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos^2\theta d\theta = 12 \displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (\cos2\theta + 1) d\theta = 12 \pi$

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot the jacobian, if you introduce a substitution $x=2u\land y=6v$ the jacobian will be $6\cdot{2}=12$ and your new region will be a circle $x^2+y^2=1$ for which the area is $r^2\pi$, here, $r=1$ , so ,$12\cdot{\pi}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int\int_{D}dxdy$$
where $D$ is the region bounded by your elipse. If you change variables $x = 2u$ and $y = 6v$ as you did, you have:
$$\int \int _{D}dxdy = \int \int_{C}|J(u,v)|dudv$$
where, now, $C$ is the region bounded by the unit circle $u^{2}+v^{2}=1$ and $J(u,v)$ is the Jacobian:
$$J(u,v) = \mbox{det}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \end{pmatrix} = \mbox{det}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 6 \end{pmatrix} = -12  $$
Thus:
$$\int \int _{D}dxdy = \int \int_{C}|J(u,v)|dudv = 12 \int \int _{C}dudv$$
but $\int \int_{C}dudv$ is the area of a circle with radius $r=1$, so $\int \int_{C}dudv = \pi$.